# Django uploading file not in MEDIA_ROOT path is giving me SuspiciousOperation error

Tags: python, django, django-uploads

I want to upload files to a path that is still in my django project, but in my `MEDIA_ROOT` path.

When I try to do this I get a `SuspiciousOperation` error.

Here are the paths as defined in my settings file:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), 'static_serve')
UPLOAD_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), 'uploads')
```

I'm doing this because I don't want the files I am uploading to be accessible via the browser and my `MEDIA_ROOT` path is.

Does anyone have any idea how I get around (fix) this error.

Comment: You can forbid the web server to publicly serve certain directories under MEDIA_ROOT.

Comment: I'm using the testing server right now ... on Windows XP. I'm also not really sure how to do that.

Comment: I don't think development server can, but any production ready web server should be able to limit access to the files. [Here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/security_tips.html#protectserverfiles) is the Apache way of doing it for example.

Comment: So, is it not possible to upload files outside of the MEDIA_ROOT path?  I was hoping it was because I am going to have to redo a ton of code if it's not possible for me to find a solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes [there is a way](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#the-built-in-filesystem-storage-class):

From docs:

> For example, the following code will
>   store uploaded files under
>   /media/photos regardless of what your
>   MEDIA_ROOT setting is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

fs = FileSystemStorage(location='/media/photos')

class Car(models.Model):
    ...
    photo = models.ImageField(storage=fs)
```

Comment: +1 This is worth knowing. Too bad OP will not vote this the best answer.

Comment: I had the same problem. Did what you (and the docs) said and I get the following exception `FileFields require an "upload_to" attribute.` I pasted the whole block here: http://dpaste.com/hold/533577/ Any ideas?

Comment: Just add the upload_to as the same value as location.

Comment: @Tom, you are wrong. location attribute is an absolute path while upload_to is relative path and it is appended to MEDIA_ROOT.